# PHP: Count number of spaces in a multiple space span

Tags: php, count, preg-replace, space

I'm scanning a form field entry (`$text`) for spaces and replacing the spaces with a blank spot using preg_replace.

```
$text=preg_replace('/\s/',' ',$text);
```

This works great, except when there are multiple consecutive spaces in a line. They are all treated as a blank.

I can use this if I know the amount of spaces there will be:

```
$text=preg_replace('/ {2,}/','**' ,$text);
```

However I will never be sure of how many spaces the input could be.

```
Sample Input 1: This is a test.
Sample Input 2: This  is a test.
Sample Input 3: This                    is a test.
```

Using both preg_replace statements above I get:

```
Sample Output 1: This is a test.
Sample Output 2: This**is a test.
Sample Output 3: This**is a test.
```

How would I go about scanning the input for consecutive spaces, counting them and setting that count to a variable to place inside the preg_replace statement for multiple spaces?

Or is there another way of doing this that I am clearly missing?

*Note: Using `&nbsp;` for the replacement works to maintain the extra spaces, but I cannot replace the space with `&nbsp;`. When I do it breaks the word-wrap in my output and breaks the words wherever the wrap happens as the string never ends and it will just wrap whenever instead of before or after a word.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: If  you are trying to remove multple spaces for a single, then `preg_match('/\s+/', ' ', $string)` would replace any number of spaces with a single. If you are trying to preserve the multiple spaces to actually show as multiple spaces, then leave them in and use a `<pre>` tag (or css `white-space` property) to preserve the whitespace.

Comment: To your first question: You can use `preg_replace_callback()` So if you find 3 spaces you can add 3 * in the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback` to count the found spaces.

```
$text = 'This  is a test.';

print preg_replace_callback('/ {1,}/',function($a){
     return str_repeat('*',strlen($a[0]));
},$text);
```

Result: `This**is*a*test.`

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having the issue when trying to use nbsp and word wrap, but that' s because HTML is just collapsing the large white space.

That's a whole other issue. This gets me what I need. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

if you want replace  multiple space with single space  you could use

```
$my_result =  preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternation with two lookarounds to check if there's a whitespace before or after:

```
$text = preg_replace('~\s(?:(?=\s)|(?<=\s\s))~', '*', $text);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dFMR8W/1)

details:

```
\s  # a whitespace
(?:
    (?=\s)     # followed by 1 whitespace
  | # OR
    (?<=\s\s)  # preceded by 2 whitespaces (including the previous)
)
```